# My Chrysler 300C drove through high water now won't start

Tags: battery, starting, fuel-system, chrysler-300c

I drove through a puddle of water. No problems I went home shut it off. Waited a couple hours tried to drive again. Started for a few seconds and shut off did that three times now it won't turn over at all? I need help

Comment: Check the starter and circuit, check the engine is dry - no puddles of water, no water sucked into the intake.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You state it "won't turn over" ... do you mean the engine does not make any noise (no starter, not nothing), or that there's nothing beyond the starter pushing the engine around (nothing firing)?

Comment: No but I did get my keys wet. And I tried to lock and unlock the doors and get nothing? Do you think you have something to do with my keys

Comment: Tap water, rain water and faucet water have minerals that make it conductive, meaning it carries electricity across the water, similar to how carbon paint does... but condensation or better known as distilled water is pure H20 so it's not conductive... think about that for a second: If water got into your keys, then that 3 volt battery may have shorted out a micro component, but they're usually sealed to prevent that kind of stuff from happening... so is it cracked, was it submerged... take your remote apart and look for any water damage. Do lights come on when you turn the key